# fullCalendar- how to unselect a selected date in angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm trying to unselect date when we clicked on particular selected date.
Kindly check my below code and attached screenshot.

```
export class OfcalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  calendarOptions: Options;
  displayEvent: any;
  dateStartObj:any;
  dateEndObj:any;
  dateRange:any = [];
  isDateFound:boolean= false;

  @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) ucCalendar: CalendarComponent;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.calendarOptions = {
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: false,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month'
    },
    dragScroll:false,
    selectable: true,
    events: [],
  };

}

select(model: any) {
  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
  /* event starts date  */
  this.dateStartObj = model.start._d;
  let startMonth = ("0" + (this.dateStartObj.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  let startDate = ("0" + (this.dateStartObj.getDate() + 1)).slice(-2);
  let dateStartFormat = this.dateStartObj.getFullYear() + "-" + startMonth  + "-" + startDate;


  this.isDateFound = false;
  /* check value is already present in array or not */
  for (let i=0; i < this.dateRange.length; i++) {
    if (this.dateRange[i].start == dateStartFormat) {
        this.dateRange.splice(i, 1);
        this.isDateFound = true;
        break;
    }
  }    
 /* push element in array */
  if(!this.isDateFound){
    this.dateRange.push({title  : 'event2',start  : dateStartFormat,rendering: 'background'});
    this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('unselect', true);
  }
  this.calendarOptions.events = this.dateRange;
  this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents', this.dateRange, true);
  console.log(this.dateRange);

 }


 }
```

When i clicked on selected date , that date is remove from array but selection is still look like before.
Can any one please let me know how can i proceed further?

Comment: I think you probably just want to move `this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('unselect', true);` outside its enclosing `if` block - currently it'll only remove the selection if the date is not found in the array.

Comment: I tried from that way too.but doesn't get the success

Comment: BTW the "unselect" method doesn't have a second parameter which you can send "true" to...not sure where you got that from. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/unselect-method. So if you change the code to `if(!this.isDateFound){
    this.dateRange.push({title  : 'event2',start  : dateStartFormat,rendering: 'background'});
  }     this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('unselect');` I would expect it to work

Comment: agreed. I tried this in all possible ways. but not working.

Comment: any error in the browser console at that time?

Comment: No. on unselect selected value is removed from array but that green selection color not disappear.

Comment: It's strange. In regular fullCalendar that's certainly how it's supposed to work. Perhaps it's something to do with the Angular integration. I know almost nothing about Angular so I can't really comment on that unfortunately.

Comment: anyone got solution ? im stuck...